# Write to file in PHP?

Tags: php

Well actually, I already know how to write a file, but how do I write data to a file where the newest data added is at the top? I know how to do this, but the newest information is at the bottom. By the way, just to clarify, I do need all of the data to be displayed, not just the newest one.

Comment: File system APIs typically don't include primitives to write to arbitrary locations in the file. If PHP is like other languages, you'll have to `write(prelude); write(originalContents);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean *append* or *prepend*? This will append:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
```

This will prepend:

```
$handle = fopen('file.txt', "r+");
$read = fread($handle, filesize($file));
$data = $newStuff . $read;
if (!fwrite($handle, $data)) {
    echo 'fail';
} else {
    echo 'success';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append some text to the file content it's better to use another function:

```
file_put_contents('data.txt', '123', FILE_APPEND)
```